# How to retrieve the element of the container with unique_ptr in c++?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I used vector like this:

```
int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> queue;
  queue.push_back(5);
  queue.push_back(4);
  if (!queue.empty()) {
    int data = queue.back();
    if (something_happens) {
      queue.pop_back();
    }
  }
}
```

However, If I use vectors with unique_ptr:

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<int>> queue;
```

how to use `back()`?

Should I pass the ownership to the element of `unique_ptr` to the caller of `back()` even if the `pop()` does not occur?

If I have to pass the ownership, how the container again takes the ownership?

Answer (score 1):

> how to use `back()`?

It *depends*. If you don't want to transfer the ownership of `queue.back()`, then you can use reference to accept it

```
auto&& data = queue.back();
```

Or you can use `std::move` to transfer its ownership to the temporary variable

```
auto data = std::move(queue.back());
```

> If I have to pass the ownership, how the container again takes the
> ownership?

Similarly, just use `std::move` to transfer the ownership of `data` back to `queue.back()`

```
queue.back() = std::move(data);
```

Comment: Thank you. does first approach violate single ownership? It seems that both `queue` and `data` now share the pointer.

Comment: Since `data` is a *reference*, it's really just an alias for `queue.back()`.

Comment: In this example, `back()` will return a `unique_ptr<int>&`, not a `unique_ptr<int>&&`, so `auto&& data` should be `auto& data`

Comment: Uh-huh, `auto&&` will be automatically deduced as `unique_ptr<int>&`, which is equivalent to `auto&`.